# How can I support unicode fonts in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services, unicode

I need to show Hindi and Bengali font support in my app. How to do this.Please help.
Also tell me how can I get the support from XML, as I need to get the data through web-services.

Comment: I want to +1 for request on Hindi and Bengali font, but also -1 for support on XML, so won't vote on this one.  XML support is present in the standard android API.  Read it up.

Comment: Lock at this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is that is put a particular font of choice to assets folder and used this code:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initFont();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initFont();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initFont();
    }

    private void initFont() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"myfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

But the problem what I am facing is that the even if I am getting the fonts in my emulator some of the fonts patterns are not correct.

Reply if anybody wants to add more to my answer, you are welcome.

Comment: I had this problem.And what I have done is to convert unicode fonts to standard ASCII fonts.Now it works on all API's.